# How to connect with mongoOrion database?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I want to connect to MongoDB by GUI manager e.g [3T MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/), MongoDB Compass,Robomongo,MongoBooster.

I use windows.

How to connect with mongoOrion database by GUI manager?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand (althoug I don't know 3T MongoChef, so I may be wrong) MongoChef is expecting the URL of a MongoDB endpoint. However, you have provided the URL of the Orion Context Broker endpoint (i.e. the NGSI REST API).

You should use the URL endpoint correspondign to the MongoDB instance used by Orion. By default Orion uses the MongoDB instance running at localhost (i.e. the same host where Orion runs) on default mongo port (i.e. 27017). That default can be overriden using the  `-dbhost` [CLI parameter](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/cli/index.html#command-line-options).

Comment: How can I find the URL endpoint corresponding to the MongoDB instance? What should I enter as URL? I use windows.

Comment: I think that question should be done to the 3T MongoChef support... What I can tell regarding Orion is what has been mentioned in the answer: that Orion expect a MongoDB instance running on localhost:27017 by default and that default can be changes using `-dbhost`.